# jQuery mouseover change mouseclick

Tags: jquery, css

```
$( function() {
    $(".box").hover( function() {
        $(this).find(".overlay").fadeIn();
    }
    ,function() {
        $(this).find(".overlay").fadeOut();
    });        
});
```

This jQuery mouseover showing layer how can I edit mouse click show menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {
    $(".box").click(function () {
        var $overlay = $(this).find(".overlay");
        if ($overlay.is(':visible')) {
            $overlay.fadeOut();
        } else {
            $overlay.fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @MsntcUmbaa you can mark the answer as accepted.... there is a tick mark at the top left side of the answer you can use it

Comment: i clicked :D how can i close this layer :(